# T-SQL Combine Ranges Based On Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have been struggling with this query for hours.    I am trying to aggregate mile post ranges based off the value in the Value column. The results should have unique segments with the highest value from the Value field for each segment.  Here's an example:

---

```
Mile_Marker_Start | Mile_Marker_End | Value
      0                100              5
     50                150              6
    100                200             10
     75                300              9
    150                200              7
```

And here's the result I'm looking for:

---

```
Mile_Marker_Start | Mile_Marker_End | Value
       0                 50             5
      50                 75             6
      75                100             9
     100                200            10
     200                300             9
```

As you can see, the row with a value of 9 got split into 2 rows because Value 10 was bigger. Also, the row with Value 7 does not display because Value 10 was bigger.  Can this be done without using a cursor?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand this data. Where does the 200 come from in first column inthe second data set?

Comment: To expand on that last question ... and if 200 is present in the output, why isn't 150?

Comment: Please either explain the logic for the groupings in you desired output or update if they aren't correct. As you can see, I've added an answer, but it doesn't agree with your output. I have another possible answer which also doesn't agree ... but which includes all the "Marker Start" and "Marker End" values.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The Mile Marker columns are segments along a line so think of each row as a line segment along a road.  150 is not displayed in the result because the value of 10 is greater than 7 along that same stretch of segment.

Comment: Ok. My 'other answer' is closer, but will need some extra work before I post it.

Comment: I think you're saying that the 100 to 200 group is actually a collapsed pair of 100 - 150 and 150 - 200 which is collapsed because the value of both is 10. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following now does what you need. I'd recommend running all the parts separately so you can see what they do and how they work.

```
DECLARE @input AS TABLE
(Mile_Marker_Start int, Mile_Marker_End int, Value int)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES
(0,100,5), (50,150,6), (100,200,10), (75,300,9), (150,200,7)

DECLARE @staging as table
(Mile_Marker int)

INSERT INTO @staging
SELECT Mile_Marker_Start from @input
UNION -- this will remove duplicates
SELECT Mile_Marker_End from @input
; -- we need semi-colon for the following CTE

-- this CTE gets the right values, but the rows aren't "collapsed"
WITH all_markers AS
(
SELECT
    groups.Mile_Marker_Start,
    groups.Mile_Marker_End,
    max(i3.Value) Value
FROM
(
SELECT
    s1.Mile_Marker Mile_Marker_Start,
    min(s2.Mile_Marker) Mile_Marker_End
FROM
    @staging s1
    JOIN @staging s2 ON
        s1.Mile_Marker < s2.Mile_Marker
GROUP BY
   s1.Mile_Marker 
) as groups
JOIN @input i3 ON
    i3.Mile_Marker_Start < groups.Mile_Marker_End AND
    i3.Mile_Marker_End > groups.Mile_Marker_Start
GROUP BY
    groups.Mile_Marker_Start,
    groups.Mile_Marker_End
)

SELECT
    MIN(collapse.Mile_Marker_Start) as Mile_Marker_Start,
    MAX(collapse.Mile_Marker_End) as Mile_Marker_End,
    collapse.Value
FROM 
    (-- Subquery get's IDs for the groups we're collapsing together
    SELECT
        am.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY am.Mile_Marker_Start) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY am.Value ORDER BY am.Mile_Marker_Start) GroupID
    FROM
        all_markers am
    ) AS COLLAPSE
GROUP BY
    collapse.GroupID,
    collapse.Value
ORDER BY
    MIN(collapse.Mile_Marker_Start)
```

Comment: I've updated this to the "other" answer I mentioned. I've yet to incorporate the collapsing of rows.

Comment: I've now incorporated the collapsing of rows. Please give it a try and see how you get on.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you.  I wasn't thinking about collapsing the mile markers like you did.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on 2012 you could maybe use LEAD. Here is my code but as noted on your question by @stevelovell , we need clarification on how you are getting your result table.

    <s>--test date
    declare  @tablename TABLE
    (
       Mile_Marker_Start int,
       Mile_Marker_End int,
       Value int
    );</s>

```
insert into @tablename
      values(0,100, 5),
     (50,150, 6),
    (100,200,10),
     (75,300, 9),
    (150,200, 7);

--query
select  *
from @tablename
order by Mile_Marker_Start

select Mile_Marker_Start, 
    case when lead(mile_marker_start) over(order by mile_marker_start) < Mile_Marker_End THEN
        lead(mile_marker_start) over(order by mile_marker_start) 
        ELSE 
            Mile_marker_end
        END
        AS MILE_MARKER_END, 
     Value
from @tablename
order by Mile_Marker_Start
```

Once you update your notes I will come back and update my answer.
Update: wasn't able to get LEAD and the other windowing functions to work with your requirements. With the way you need to move up and down the table current, and calculated values...